# need help changing the size of a twitter bootstrap span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help changing the size of a twitter bootstrap span. 
Here is the page I need help with,

http://2click4.com/trender/

The right panel needs to touch the side of the screen, at the moment it is like 90% or something.

I have no idea how to do this as I have only just started using this.

Comment: Which span you want to change?

Comment: I want to change span9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using class `container-fluid` which by itself provide left padding of 20px to your span.
So, to resolve it.
Do some following steps :

- remove `margin-left : -16px` from your span.
- remove `pading-left : 20px` from `container-fluid` or overwrite it with `padding-left: 0px`.

Comment: this worked a little bit, increased the size. still a gap though

Comment: The end is that you can try changing the width of span9 to 77%(width:77%).

Answer (score 0):

You use spanX classes of boostrap, whose exist to be proportionate from a grid.
In your case i won't use it, and add my own class logic.

However if you want to customize the span3 and span9 classes you can do it :

```
.row-fluid .span3,
.row-fluid .span9 {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.row-fluid .span3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.row-fluid .span9 {
    width: 75%;
}
```

Be advised that it will modify all span3 and span9 inside a .row-fluid.
I won't recommend using it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.container-fluid { padding-right: 20px;}` it will solve your problem